# How to read and write data on CSV file using DB connector in Mule 3.8

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

How to read and write data on CSV file using DB connector in Mulesoft

Answer (score 0):

The DB connector returns Java, so after the connector, you would have a transform message component that converts that Java to a CSV.

Comment: Could you please share me more details.

Comment: You're asking an incredibly general question, so the best I can give you is a general answer. If you'd like more details, I'd be happy to provide them if you provide a more detailed question.